# 2 different results for a rotated area using the disc method

Tags: integration

When using the disk method, why does the area between the curve $4x^2+y^2=16 $ (an ellipse) and the x-axis create a volume of rotation around the $x$-axis, equal to twice the volume for the same curve and the $y$-axis when rotated around the $y$-axis?

Ellipse = $4x^2+y^2=16$
(1) rotation axis $x: y^1=16-4x^2$, pi.integral of $16-4x^2 dx$ between 2 et -2 = Volume = π.128/3
(2) rotation axis $y: x^2=4-(y^2/4)$, pi.integral of $4-(y^2/4)dx$ between 4 et -4=Volume = π.64/3

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I don't know why the results differ by a factor of 2 (it might be obvious from the calculations, I haven't tried performing those), but as the area you rotate is not symmetric relative to the two axes, it's quite obvious that you get bodies of different volume when doing so.

Comment: Volume of ellipsoid with semi-axes $a,b,c$ is $\frac{4\pi}{3}abc$. In those two rotations, the ellipsoids have semi-axes $2,4,4$ and $2,2,4$. Hence the ratio $2:1$.